# How can I use SEF form URL and escape question mark in it?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I use the `Symfony` form builder for filtering products in my web shop. So when form is submitted, I get the URL like:

```
/category?vendor=apple+htc&price=500-1000
```

But I need to use more `SEF URL`, looks like:

```
/category/apple+htc/500-1000
```

or with ID of properties

```
/category/173-181-159-160
```

or maybe like hash:

```
/category/21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
```

What better to use and how can I realize it with `Symfony` forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it would be helpful to see more code(category Action, formBuilder code).
Without the code i assume you are sending parameters (as apple and htc) and filtering in the controller.

If you want your forms URL to be SEF you have to set it yourself in forms action attribute.  Symfony can help you with backend data manipulation, not with frontend. You could use javascript for dynamical `action` setting. First you attach onChange events to your form elements and send changed values to this function:

```
function changeAction(phoneModel, priceRange){
    //some logic to transform values of your form items to SEF url elements
    document.getElementById('form_id').action = "/category/" + phoneModel +
    + "/" + priceRange; 
}
```

When the form is submitted it will be submited to the URL you specified in forms `action`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with symfony routing?

Example:

```
category:
pattern:  /category/{vendor}/{price}/{other_params}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeNameBundle:Category, price: false, other_params: false }
```

Comment: I need to build this route from sent form request :)

Comment: I still doesn't see any problem because you know all your params in form and you can set its default value to false.
Your form need to have action to @category route and evrithing will works fine.
Anyway, it is your choice.

Comment: Yes, you right, but action in form must be generated with JS, and you don't  mentioned it in your answer.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to tell you that you not need any JS here because your form have method GET.

Comment: Ok, so how can I pass form params like in your answer without JS? ) Form pass params with GET method like: `/category?vendor=apple&price=500`, so I need to generate form method like in your answer with JS

Comment: No, SF routing will do all job for you. You just need to add name of SF route in form action like I said before.

Comment: Hm, it's interesting, but now I have more complex task with unlimited properties. I will try your solution later, thanks for explanation

Comment: If you doesn't know all your possible params check this out :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415965/routing-an-unlimited-number-of-parameters